# Angular service instantiated twice?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

somehow I've got a service that seems to be instantiated twice (its properties are not in sync), by doing the following:

```
@Component
export class MyComponent extends someOtherComponent {
  constructor(service: Service, service2: Service2) {
    super(service, service2);
  }

  isStateEqual() {
    return this.service.serviceState === this.service2.service.serviceState;
  }
}

@Injectable
export class Service {
  serviceState = {}
}

@Injectable
export class Service2 {
  constructor(service: Service) {}
}
```

This is just a very basic example, but that's what it comes down to. To be more precise: We're building our own datepicker and extending NgbDatepicker component which has KeyMapService (this uses NgbDatepickerService) and a local NgbDatepickerService.
Here is a link to the component: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

In our app isStateEqual will always return false (even right after initialising the component) while in the demo you can find in the link above it will always return true (which is how it should be).

Anyone knows why it could be like that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Dennis

Comment: is it a pseudo-code? why don't you use parentheses after decorators otherwice?

Comment: Just pseudo-code ofc. Putting the whole stuff in here would've been quite much.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for this?

Comment: you probably can take service1 from service2 instead of injecting it directly as a workaround. to understand the whole picture we need to see your providers declarations

Comment: If your Service && Service2 are declare in the same module that's not must happen :(

Comment: @PavelAgarkov that's sadly not a solution for us, because we're extending NgbDatepicker and they're injecting both the services like that. We don't really want to change anything about their code.

Comment: @Eliseo We've got one datepicker.module.ts in which we provide both services.

Comment: I mean `super(service2.service, service2);`

Comment: @PavelAgarkov Great idea, thought we could do that. Sadly that doesn't work though, because service in service2 is private - I just changed it to public to test isStateEqual(), but changing it to public would also involve modifying the ngb library.

Answer (score 5):

Application wide singletons must be defined on the bootstrapped module:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)

@NgModule({
  providers: [SingletonService1, SingletonService2],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6344#issuecomment-169957199)

or by setting `providedIn: 'root'` on the service decorator:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

[source](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service)

Answer (score 5):

In my case the service was instantiated twice, because I imported the service using two different approaches (my IDE (VS2019) mishelped me here by automatically generating the incorrect import):

```
import { Service } from '@mycompany/mymodule'
```

and

```
import { Service } from '../../../dist/@mycompany/mymodule/@mycompany-mymodule';
```

Answer (score 3):

Visual code import my service in this way automatically

```
import { ConfigService } from 'src/app/services/config.services.js';
```

And the correct way is:

```
import { ConfigService } from 'src/app/services/config.services';
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you declare the provider for your services - this determines the scoping. You don't specify in your question where you've done this - try doing it in AppModule, for example.

Comment: Sorry. We've got a datepicker.module.ts in which both services (service and service2) are provided.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with where the services are provided. They're - as I said - within our datepicker.module, but theyre also provided within the NgbDatepicker component we're extending. Sadly it's still not working if I remove the providers from that external component temporarily. Still that could be it.

Comment: if you use providers in your component, that's create a new instance of the service. In that case, I think that there is nothing to do

Answer (score -1):

"service" must be a public propertie of Service2.

```
@Injectable
export class Service2 {
  service:Service
  constructor(service: Service) 
  {
      this.service=service;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a private property actually. I changed it to public to make my "isStateEqual()" work, but I can't do that because I'd be modifying the external lib.  I didn't write that in my pseudo-code, sorry.